# Can we create a Pod which in turn uses many pods?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, cocoapods, podspec

I am going to build a pod which will be using multiple pods with in it, Can we achieve this? what  are the things I should keep in mind while building this?

Comment: yes a cocoapod can have dependencies. Read the tutorials / documentation on the cocoapods website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build separate pods and then build one metapod, that depends on the others.